# Move directory and it's content vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to move the folder and its contents to another directory. This means the folder and contents will no longer exist from the source and will be moved to its destination. But when the destination path has the same folder name, it will just overwrite the folder and its content.
I'm getting error if same folder exists in the destination path using the code below.
The catch here is I don't exactly know the folder name and filename here inside the source path. I just know where I'm going to get the folder and files to move to its destination.

I've used these codes but couldn't figure out how to overwrite:

'web.config

```
      Sourcepath = "C:\TestSource\"

      Destinationpath =  "C:TestDestiation\"
```

'calling the move function:

```
            dInfoSource = New DirectoryInfo(ccConfigClass.SourcePath)
            dInfoDestination = New DirectoryInfo(ccConfigClass.DestinationPath)
            MoveContents(dInfoSource, dInfoDestination)

  Public Sub MoveContents(sourcePath As DirectoryInfo, destinationPath As DirectoryInfo)
     Try
        If (Not destinationPath.Exists) Then
            destinationPath.Create()
        End If

        'Move all Files
        For Each file As FileInfo In sourcePath.GetFiles()
            file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destinationPath.FullName, file.Name))
        Next

        'Move all folders
        For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In sourcePath.GetDirectories()
            dir.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destinationPath.FullName, dir.Name))
        Next

      Catch ex As Exception
        Dim objErrorLogger As New ErrorLogging
        objErrorLogger.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name, ex.Message.ToString, ex)
      End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: When you say overwrite, do you mean to merge the contents or replace?  If the latter, then you should just test for prior existence of destination path and delete, before doing your move.

Comment: Would have to replace the entire folder and content

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.moveto?view=net-6.0#system-io-fileinfo-moveto(system-string-system-boolean)

Comment: `DirectoryInfo` has a `.MoveTo()` method. It might be easier.

Comment: @tgolisch, I'm already using that. But getting an error whenever there is an existing folder.

Comment: ... and that error is what exactly?

Comment: [Cannot create a file when that file already exists.] That's the error.

Comment: Then test for directory existence and if true delete the directory before the move.  Note that `Directory.Delete` takes two parameters, path and a Boolean.  If the Boolean is True then the Directory is deleted together with any files and sub-directories (which is what I presume you want?)

Comment: The catch here is I don't exactly know the folder name and filename here inside the source path. I just know where I'm going to get the folder and files to move to its destination. I cannot exactly delete the directory because it has other folders and files. 
Let's say the Sourcepath = "C:\TestSource\", what I really to move is the folder and files inside this path: "C:\TestSource\. It may have this "C:\TestSource\SourceFolder\SourceFile.text". Then I need to move that to the Destinationpath =  "C:TestDestiation\".

Comment: I will have a conflict if  there is already existing "C:TestDestiation\SourceFolder\SourceFile.text". There is no particular folder name or filename that I have to move, I just know that whatever inside Sourcepath = "C:\TestSource\" needs to be moved to Destinationpath =  "C:TestDestiation\".